# Open link in browser with different params every 5 second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post, get

I want to open link `example.com/id=` with a different ids every 5 second using JS/jQuery.

I tried this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
setInterval(function() {
    var i = 1;
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            console.log(request.responseText);
         }
      }
     var add = 'example.com?id='+i;      
    request.open('GET', add, true);
    i = i + 1;
    request.send();

}, 5000);
</script>
```

but this is not working for me.

What should I do?

Comment: actually you asked for open a link in browser but this code is sending an AJAX request to server with different parameter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using local variable `i`, so for every interval, this variable is reset to its initial value 1. Try using global variable instead of local:

```
var i = 1;
setInterval(function() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            console.log(request.responseText);
         }
      }
     var add = 'example.com/id='+i;      
    request.open('GET', add, true);
    i = i + 1;
    request.send();

}, 5000);
```

or to avoid putting variable into global scope. You could wrap your function inside an immediate function. Like this:

```
(function(){
    var i = 1;
    setInterval(function() {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
             if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                console.log(request.responseText);
             }
          }
         var add = 'example.com/id='+i;      
        request.open('GET', add, true);
        i = i + 1;
        request.send();

    }, 5000);
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you've tagged it with jquery, here is one way:

```
$(function() {
    var id = 1;
    setInterval(function(){ 
        $.get("example.com", { id: id }, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            id++;
        })
        .fail(function(xhr, status, error) { 
            console.log("XHR:: " + xhr + " | Status:: " + status + " | Error:: " + error);
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sarathsprakash/kwQLf/)**

You have to specify the declaration of i `var i=1;`outside the `setInterval()`

Try this

### code

```
var i = 1;
self.setInterval(function(){

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
            console.log(request.responseText);
            alert(request.responseText);  // alert response
         }
      }
     var add = 'example.com?id='+i;      
    request.open('GET', add, true);
    i = i + 1;
    request.send();
},5000);
```

Hope this helps,thank you